# Flutter-Firestore: Add Value to Array That Already Exists

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there an easy way to add a value to an array in Firestore that already exists? I know `arrayUnion()` will not add a value to the array if it already exists, and I have read older replies that the only way to do this is to read the entire document, and then completely re-write the array, but that is incredibly inefficient (and could get expensive). Is there not a better way to do this in Firebase?

For example, if my value for `update` already exists in my array, I still want it to add it to my array.

```
'unitsLog': FieldValue.arrayUnion([update])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `arrayUnion` operator explicitly only adds items that don't exist in the array yet.

If you want to add duplicates, you'll have to:

1. Read the document from the database.
2. Update the array contents in your application code.
3. Write the entire array back to the database.